# IIS Apache Tomcat redirect

Tags: tomcat, redirect, iis

Windows 2012 Server IIS 8.5 followed instructions specified in this [How To Article](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html).

When I run the application redirect not working as expected instead of serving a login page it is downloading a application/x-msdownload with my tomcat application name and that file containing jiberish

Workers.properties

```
worker.list=list1
worker.list1.type=ajp13
worker.list1.host=localhost
worker.list1.port=8009
```

uriworkermap.properties

```
/sampleApp/*=list1
/sampleApp/servlet/*=list1
```

Comment: Update your post with the following: [1] The content of your **isapi_redirect.properties** file. [2] The relevant portion of **isapi_redirect.log** when the login page is not shown as expected.  [3] Your configuration of the AJP connector in **server.xml**. [4] The version of **isapi_redirect.dll** that you are using.

Comment: IIS can host Tomcat directly via HttpPlatformHandler, so you can forget about the middle man, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/manjug/2015/11/27/understanding-iis-httpplatformhandler-using-tomcat-8/

Comment: @skomisa -- added properties to question and no log file is generated. isapi_direct.dll is downloaded from here https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/jk/binaries/win64/jk-1.2.28/amd64/

Comment: @Lex Li never heard of http platform handler is this serve same purpose?

Comment: Java on Microsoft Azure App Service is driven by it.

Comment: on windows 2012 server needed to install azure app? what are pre-requisites?